# How can I search GitHub for an example of how to use DBObject in Java?

Tags: java, github

A possible solution to one problem I'm having has led me to wonder if/how I can searh GitHub for an example of how DB Object and BasicDBObjct are used. http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.0/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html
https://api.mongodb.com/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBObject.html

This blog post on GitHub leads me to believe it is possible: https://github.com/blog/202-github-code-search

but when I go to https://github.com/search/advanced where it's been implemented, I can't seem to get beyond searching for example of DBObject being used in the repository name.

For example: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dbobject++language%3AJava&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=Java&l=

Was this functionality taken out or am I missing a really simple search parameter?

Answer (score 0):

From your search results, click the "Code" tab at the top. That should bring you here: https://github.com/search?l=&q=dbobject++language%3AJava&ref=advsearch&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93, which I think is what you're looking for.